# Weird CORS errors on fresh vue cli project

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I just started building my second Vue project, and for the first time I wanted to use the Vue CLI and NPM rather than just loading Vue via CDN.
Installing the CLI and setting up the project worked without problems, but when I ran "npm run serve" and navigated to localhost:8080 in my browser (latest Firefox) to see if it worked, I got the following error message in my browser console multiple times:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://10.126.86.51:8080/sockjs-node/info?t=1584021154635. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
```

I also get this error message once right after loading the page:

```
[WDS] Disconnected!
```

Does anyone know what these errors mean, why I get them and how I can get rid of them?
The first one seems to be related to some kind of cross-origin call that the app is making using the host's actual IP rather than localhost, but I can't think of any reason why it would, given that I literally just installed and served the example project and did not change anything after running "vue create"

Edit: I am on Ubuntu 19.10 Desktop

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: i think This has nothing to do with Vue.
the API or the URL/IP Adress that you are calling is not allowed to be called from the location/host you call it from (your browser), which is why the command fails. Did you tried also other API Urls?

Comment: For what it's worth, the `sock-js` request is normal for a CLI project (or at least it is for me). I've never dug in to find out what it's for but I've always assumed it's related to hot reloading. I too see an IP address even if I try to use localhost. For me the requests succeed no problem, so I don't get the error messages. It looks like your requests are using `https` whereas mine use `http`, so I wonder whether it's just a certificate problem that's causing them to fail.

Comment: [This article here might help you](https://medium.com/js-dojo/how-to-deal-with-cors-error-on-vue-cli-3-d78c024ce8d3). It seems to be quite a common issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, what kind of OS you are working on? If you are working on unix based systems, a service (like nginx) could produce this error. If so, try stopping it.

Afterwards I would try to run your application from vue ui.

Type in your terminal:

```
vue ui
```

This starts the web based graphical user interface of vue cli. You can handle your app development from there by starting your service and run your build command.

ATTENTION: you must add (import, NOT create) your project (root folder) to the UI.

If you get the same error inside your browser console, set up a vagrant box. First steps are explained here:

https://www.vagrantup.com/intro/getting-started/

Follow instructions for project setup.

Simplest way would be running

```
vagrant init
```

inside your project folder. Therefore you don't have to setup a new project.

After running the init command, try running

```
npm run serve
```

or use vue UI instead (as explained above), if you prefer it.

If the problem still exists, more infos about your OS would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks! Using Vue UI did not solve the problem in and of itself, but when I explicitly set the host to "localhost" in "parameters" the errors disappeared. the requests still happen, but they don't fail. So this has solved the problem. I guess for some reason the dev server uses localhost in one place and the actual IP in another by default.